# URL with hashtag scrolls in Firefox, not Safari, Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, url

I have some links that when you click it, takes you to another page and appends a hash to scroll to a certain div on that page in this format: http://domain.com#respond

This works as expected in Firefox but Safari and Chrome remove the hash and stays at the top of the page. Here's my page: http://katielopezphotography.com/blog/

Click on the 'add comment' at the bottom of each page. It's supposed to load the single post and scroll to the comments section.

Comment: No, it's working in the chrome too.

Comment: It only scrolls down to about half the page on Chrome.

Comment: No it goes down but comes again at the middle when an image is loading.

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is made by slow loading images. I had the same problem with anchors in jQuery tabs. The browser goes correctly to that anchor, but then the images are loading and the browser doesn't go again to that anchor. As I saw you had jQuery on your blog, a simple solution would be this:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    if (window.location.hash != '') {
        window.location.hash = window.location.hash;
    }
});
</script>
```

This code will trigger after the dom and the images has loaded and go to the specific anchor.